# Grab current OpenGL context with Qt

Tags: qt, opengl

I have written a Qt based dll with some OpenGL calls. If I load my DLL from my Qt application with QGLWidget used for rendering, a call to QGLContext::currentContext from the DLL returns the correct context. But if use my DLL in a non Qt based program there is no QGLContext returned. As a result I couldn't use QGLShaderProgram in non Qt based apps.

What I am doing wrong?

P.S. Direct calls to glCreateProgram and so on in my library seem to work fine, but I want to use Qt classes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want to use Qt classes.

Then you should use your DLL in an application that uses Qt. By requiring the Qt classes, your DLL now requires ***Qt***. If you want your DLL to work when Qt isn't available, then you shouldn't use Qt.

Besides, the Qt classes for shaders and programs aren't anything you couldn't whip up in 30 minutes.

Comment: "By requiring the Qt classes, your DLL now requires Qt" It's not a problem. Problem is how to use QGLShader class to render on existing OpenGL context created from non Qt program.

Unfortunatly links which you a provided related Qt 5 (un stable), so I can not use them

Comment: You don't. Either use Qt or don't use it. You can perhaps jump through hoops to make it work, but why would you?

Comment: @Jeka: "It's not a problem. Problem is how to use QGLShader class to render on existing OpenGL context created from non Qt program." Then that *is* your problem. You can't *kinda* use Qt (or at least, not the OpenGL parts). Either the *application as a whole* uses Qt or it doesn't. And if your DLL is being used by a non-Qt application, then your *application* doesn't use Qt. So neither can you.

Comment: This is an old discussion - in the interest of people coming here to learn, the comments made by Nicol and Bart were correct at the time, but are no longer true. Qt has nearly 100% replaced their GL interfaces, and this is now supported. See QOpenGLContext::setNativeHandle()